# Benefit of sprites for WebSocket applications?

Tags: meteor, websocket, sprite

In normal web applications, it is good practice to package multiple images in sprites such as to diminish the number of HTTP requests, and therefore minimize loading time...

My question is: does this benefit still exist in WebSocket based applications?

Since a WebSocket application does not technically make HTTP requests, will there be a performance increase when using sprites in this case too?

**Note:** I know that sprites have other advantages such as a better user experience when switching a button from idle/hover, but I'm here talking only about load time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so my question was motivated by a surprisingly low overhead when using individual frames vs. sprites on a Meteor application. Turns out, this is due not to WebSocket but to HTTP/2. Some resources which answer it:

- [Under what circumstances would loading images individually with HTTP/2 be slower than loading all images at once with a sprite a la HTTP/1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163102/under-what-circumstances-would-loading-images-individually-with-http-2-be-slower/35599342#35599342)
- [Loading 1 1MB large image (spritesheet) vs loading 100 10KB images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048569/loading-1-1mb-large-image-spritesheet-vs-loading-100-10kb-images/41091555#41091555) -
- [Optimizing File Cacheing and HTTP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588692/optimizing-file-cacheing-and-http2/36253257#36253257)

Comment: how are you measuring overhead?

Comment: We're measuring the entire load time of the page. It has a massive number of graphical assets, around 5000, but we saw only a 20% increase in load time when using single images vs. sprites of 16 images.